# Nexus 5 stuck on boot when trying to update to Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, unbricking, 5.0-lollipop

I was trying to update to Android 5 using Nexus Root Toolkit. I clicked the "Start" on my Nexus 5 by mistake. Now, my phone stucks on the Google logo.

I tried to wipe and restore so I can start over, but the same thing happens; it stucks on Google logo. How to fix this?

Comment: In order for a proper answer the question needs to be edited to contain more information. Such as what steps and other.

Comment: Had to flash the image from google, mine was previously rooted. Had the same issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turned out to be an issue with the rooted boot.img.
Try the option to flash stock rom with the 'soft brick/bootloop' option checked.
I now have lollipop working, but no root access yet. But this is better than a bricked phone...